# Send a file in socket.io without changing the user's window location

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, sockets, socket.io

I am looking to see if there is a way to send an html file to a socket.io connection without disconnecting them and changing their window location. Right now I have it set up where if someone tries to access my website they will be prompted to enter a name. When this name is entered and the user presses play they will be sent the /game directory on the website. They will also emit their name along with the connection info. At the moment when they connect to the /game directory it disconnects the user causing their information (including their name) to be removed from the player list. Then when the player joins onto the /game directory they have a name of null and their info is entirely new info like coordinates and things. Here is the code I use to detect a request for /game:

```js
//Sends home page that asks for name.
app.get('/',function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client/home.html");
});
//Sends game file when /game is requested
app.get('/game',function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client/game.html");
});
```

Is there any way to stop the user from disconnecting when they change to the game screen? this way I can keep their info? or Is there something else I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: You can basically send anything with websockets, but what you have is routes, you'd have to send the data to the client, and insert the markup there etc, same as you would with ajax, which is generally a better option for this kind of thing.

Comment: @adeneo Not sure I understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Every time you change your URI in browser you should reconnect your websocket connection.

My advice is **use single page aplication**. Backend will send only data by socket or/and REST. Frontend will render data from backend. Now you have view on your backend and have this problem with reconnecting web sockets.